# Custom Listview with different row layouts (position problems)

Tags: java, android, list, listview, row

I'm creating custom listview. Everything works fine. But when i launch application problem arrise with layouts. It should be

- row1
- row2
- row1
- row2

But sometimes it just do something like this

- row1
- row2
- row1
- row1
- row2

and so on. 
Here is the code snippet, where i change row layouts.

```
View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null )
    {
        if(position % 2 == 0)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent,false);
        else
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row2, parent,false);
    }

    if(position % 3 == 0)
        vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#178C70"));
    else if(position % 3 == 1)
        vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E51F2A"));
    else vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1C2023"));
```

added pictures so you can see my problem.:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN2Lq.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated that this.

Short answer, in your adapter, please implement these methods:

`public int getItemViewType(int position)`

`public int getViewTypeCount()`

Or even better go and read this tutorial http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296